# Orchestral/tenanti multi database

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, multi-database

I build an application for many tenants and each tenant has it's own database. The name of the database is the same as the tenants id.(the id exists out of five numbers). After authentication the user should be connected with his own database and redirected to his dashboard.

I tried to connect the user with his database with the following code, which I placed in Authenticate.php

```
if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->tenant) {
        $user = Auth::id();
        Tenanti::driver('user')->asDefaultDatabase($user, 'users_{id}');
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'user_'.$user); 
    }
```

The if statement checks in the main database if the logged in user is a tenant(boolean).

The config/database.php contains the following code:

```
 'tenants' => [
        'user_1' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',     // for user with id=1
            'database'  => '86097',     // for user with id=1
            'username'  => 'root', // for user with id=1
            'password'  => 'root', // for user with id=1
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            ],
        ],
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Orchestra\Support\Facades\Tenanti;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
{
    Tenanti::setupMultiDatabase('tenants', function (User $entity, array $template) {
        $template['database'] = "user_{$entity->getKey()}";

        return $template;
    });
}
}
?>
```

I don't get an error, but the connection hasn't changed. The user database is empty and therefore I shouldn't see any data when I log in with user_id=1 . Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration should be:

```
'tenants' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',     // for user with id=1
    'database'  => '86097',     // for user with id=1
    'username'  => 'root', // for user with id=1
    'password'  => 'root', // for user with id=1
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Other than that please replace `Tenanti::setupMultiDatabase()` with `Tenanti::connection()` (we have deprecated the old method).

And change the following:

Tenanti::driver('user')->asDefaultConnection(Auth::user(), 'tenants_{id}');

Obviously if you want to use `users_{id}` you would then need to replace all `tenants` to `users`.

Comment: I changed the above things, but the data is still showing up, however the tenants' database is completely empty. Besides that how can I add an second and third user when the configuration is only there for user with id=1?

Comment: Read https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti#setup-model-observer

To be honest it better to understand the concept of building multi-tenant on a single database first before skipping a lots of things and assume that a one click install would solve everything.

Some code example:

https://github.com/crynobone/todoist/compare/master...single-database

https://github.com/crynobone/todoist/compare/single-database...multi-database

p/s: it's incomplete, as I never design it to solve everything.

Comment: I've succeed to implement a multi tenant single database. Thanks for helpful example. Does the application need much modification to make it a multi database system? Each user has at least four large tables(over one million rows each) Therefore I think the best solution is to have a multi database system. Correct me if I am wrong.